# Can the ExtJS GridPanel support column groups?

Tags: extjs

I would like to have a gridpanel with columns that are broken into 2 sub-columns, kind of like this:

`|   Monday   |  Tuesday  |  Wednesday  |  Thursday  |`

`| In | Out | In | Out  |  In  | Out  |  In | Out  |`

`|  9  |  4   | 10 |   5  |  8:30| 4    |  10 | 5    |`

Is this possible with ExtJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is definitively possible. However, you will not find this as out-of-the-box functionality. There is [a user extension/plugin](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76322) [(2.0 here)](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=22337) that should do the trick for you. There is also an example in the [ExtGWT samples demo](http://www.extjs.com/examples/#columngrouping) that has similar functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In Ext 4.1.3 You can see http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/grid/group-header-grid.html

It supports group headers.